# Primefaces DataTable - Complex example: No value on selected row

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatables

I'm trying execute the DataTable example avaiable on [Primefaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableComplex.jsf). All functions works but when i select a row, the value of the selected row isn't displayed on my `<p:dialog>`.

I've already checked all alternatives and nothing works. Could someone help me?

I'm using Primefaces 3.3 and glassfish 3.0.1. Here goes my code:

dataTableComplex.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <h:head>

    </h:head>

    <body>

        <h:form id="form">

            <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.cars}" rowKey="#{car.model}" paginator="true" rows="10"
                         selection="#{tableBean.selectedCar}" selectionMode="single" id="carsTable">

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":form:display" oncomplete="carDialog.show()" />

                <f:facet name="header">
                    List of Cars
                </f:facet>

                <p:column headerText="Model" sortBy="#{car.model}" filterBy="#{car.model}" id="model">
                    #{car.model}
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Year" sortBy="#{car.year}" filterBy="#{car.year}" id="year">
                    #{car.year}
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Manufacturer" sortBy="#{car.manufacturer}" filterBy="#{car.manufacturer}" id="manufacturer">
                    #{car.manufacturer}
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Color" sortBy="#{car.color}" filterBy="#{car.color}" id="color">
                    #{car.color}"
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

            <p:dialog header="Car Detail" widgetVar="carDialog" resizable="false"
                      width="200" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode">

                <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">                  

                    <h:outputText value="Model:" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{tableBean.selectedCar.model}" id="model"/>

                    <h:outputText value="Year:" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{tableBean.selectedCar.year}" id="year"/>

                    <h:outputText value="Manufacturer:" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{tableBean.selectedCar.manufacturer}" id="manufacturer"/>

                    <h:outputText value="Color:" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{tableBean.selectedCar.color}" id="color"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>            
    </body>

</html>
```

TableBean.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "tableBean")
@SessionScoped

public class TableBean implements Serializable {

private final static String[] colors;

private final static String[] manufacturers;

static {
    colors = new String[10];
    colors[0] = "Black";
    colors[1] = "White";
    colors[2] = "Green";
    colors[3] = "Red";
    colors[4] = "Blue";
    colors[5] = "Orange";
    colors[6] = "Silver";
    colors[7] = "Yellow";
    colors[8] = "Brown";
    colors[9] = "Maroon";

    manufacturers = new String[10];
    manufacturers[0] = "Mercedes";
    manufacturers[1] = "BMW";
    manufacturers[2] = "Volvo";
    manufacturers[3] = "Audi";
    manufacturers[4] = "Renault";
    manufacturers[5] = "Opel";
    manufacturers[6] = "Volkswagen";
    manufacturers[7] = "Chrysler";
    manufacturers[8] = "Ferrari";
    manufacturers[9] = "Ford";
}

private List<Car> cars;

private Car selectedCar;

private Car[] selectedCars;

public TableBean() {
    cars = new ArrayList<Car>();

    populateRandomCars(cars, 50);
}

public Car getSelectedCar() {
    return selectedCar;
}

public void setSelectedCar(Car selectedCar) {
    this.selectedCar = selectedCar;
}

private void populateRandomCars(List<Car> list, int size) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
        list.add(new Car(getRandomModel(), getRandomYear(), getRandomManufacturer(), getRandomColor()));
}

private int getRandomYear() {
    return (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 1960);
}

private String getRandomColor() {
    return colors[(int) (Math.random() * 10)];
}

private String getRandomManufacturer() {
    return manufacturers[(int) (Math.random() * 10)];
}

private String getRandomModel() {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8);
}

public List<Car> getCars() {
    return cars;
}
}
```

Car.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean(name = "car")
@SessionScoped

public class Car implements Serializable {

private String model;
private int year;
private String manufacturer;
private String color;
private int price;

public Car(){

}
public Car(String model, int year, String manufacturer, String color) {
            this.model = model;
            this.year = year;
            this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
            this.color = color;
    }

    public Car(String model, int year, String manufacturer, String color, int price) {
            this.model = model;
            this.year = year;
            this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
            this.color = color;
    this.price = price;
    }

    public String getModel() {
            return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
            this.model = model;
    }

    public int getYear() {
            return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
            this.year = year;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
            return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
            this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public String getColor() {
            return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
            this.color = color;
    }

 public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if(obj == null)
                    return false;

            if(!(obj instanceof Car))
                    return false;

            Car compare = (Car) obj;

            return compare.model.equals(this.model);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 1;

        return hash * 31 + model.hashCode();
    }

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Car{" + "model=" + model + ", year=" + year + ", manufacturer=" + manufacturer + ", color=" + color + ", price=" + price + '}';
}
}
```

Edited: to solve this problem just add @ViewScoped on TableBean.java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TableBean should be ViewScoped.

Add @ViewScoped on top of TableBean or configure it using faces-config.xml file.

Comment: You are right! Thanks! This solved my problem :)
@RinaldoPJr thanks for your patience too!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the example from the [Showcase **Labs**](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableComplex.jsf), which is running on PrimeFaces version 3.4 (still in development at time of posting).

Since you are using PrimeFaces 3.3, you should be using the examples from the common [Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableComplex.jsf).

Remember that the **Labs** version of the Showcase is always running on the still-on-development versions, while the common Showcase is always on the lastest final release.

You can always see what version is running behind the Showcase by checking the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @RinaldoPJr. 

But there is no difference between the DataTable codes. The DataTable from Showcase Lab has the same code of the common Showcase.

Even so, I have re-built the code using the common Showcase example and the problem continues.

Comment: @JoãoAlmeida There are many differences between the 2 of them. Could you please update your question with the new code? And, if possible, copy/paste your code, not the one in the Showcase. By the way, the CarDataModel is not used in the Complex Datatable example, then there is no need for you to include it in your project.

Comment: Have you also checked if there are no JavaScript error messages on the browser console (F12 in most browsers), and no JSF error messages on the IDE console?

Comment: I'm trying execute the Showcase example, so my code is the Showcase code :)
Since the common Showcase page doesn't have the Car class i've searched and found it on [Google Code page of PrimeFaces][1].

The common Showcase show the CarDataModel.java as source too. I thought it would be useful. 

Anyway, I've tried without the CarDataModel and the problem persists. The Table works: show the data, the filter works but when I select a row the data doesn't appear on dialog. No error on console IDE was encountered. 

I've edited the question with this code.

[1]:http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/

Answer (score 0):

Since class Car is just a common class, not a manage bean, You don't need the declaration:

@ManagedBean(name = "car")
@SessionScoped